# C# console app (WMI query) suddenly fills the memory

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have a C# application which creates a CimSession or a ManagementScope connection and queries the "PercentProcessorTime" parallel on dozens of remote PCs in every second.
Usually the app is working fine for a couple of hours and then suddenly starts filling up the memory. The RAM usage from the average 100MB jumps so 4-5GB in an hour.
I am unable to find out what is happening here.
Here are the two method which are running in every seconds:

```
public static bool DumpProcessesCpu(string hostname)
    {
        bool overTreshold = false;
        try
        {
            CimSessionOptions sessionOptions = new CimSessionOptions() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
            using (CimSession mySession = CimSession.Create(hostname, sessionOptions))
            {
                string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
                
                IEnumerable<CimInstance> queryInstance = mySession.QueryInstances(Namespace, "WQL", queryString);

                foreach (CimInstance cimInstance in queryInstance)
                {
                    int currentValue = Convert.ToInt32(cimInstance.CimInstanceProperties["PercentProcessorTime"].Value);
                    if (showLiveData == "true") Log.Debug("{0} - {1}", hostname, currentValue.ToString());

                    if (currentValue >= treshold)
                    {
                        overTreshold = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SystemException e)
        {
            Log.Error("An error occurred while querying for WMI data for " + hostname + ": " + e.Message);
        }
        return overTreshold;
    }
```

and

```
public static bool DumpProcessesCpuLegacy(string hostname)
    {
        bool overTreshold = false;
        try
        {  
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(queryString);
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + hostname + @"\root\cimv2", options);
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
            {    
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    int currentValue = Convert.ToInt32("" + queryObj["PercentProcessorTime"]);
                    if (showLiveData == "true") Log.Debug("{0} - {1}", hostname, currentValue.ToString());

                    if (currentValue >= treshold)
                    {
                        overTreshold = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            Log.Error("An error occurred while querying for WMI data for " + hostname + ": " + e.Message);
        }

        return overTreshold;
    }
```

I am using Parallel.Foreach to run one of these methods on every remote PC in every second.
I am using extensive logging and try-catch everywhere and there are no error messages.

What could be the problem here? Where should I continue the investigation?

Thank you

Comment: Try to dispose `ManagementObject queryObj` at the end of the `foreach` loop. Not sure it helps, but `ManagementObject` implements `IDisposable`, so it should also be disposed when used in a loop

Comment: Good point, I will definitely give it a try. I thought that because the queryObj was inside the 'using statement' it got disposed automatically.

Comment: No, that only applies to the `searcher` instance. Unfortunately, `foreach (using ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())` isn't allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately disposing ManagementObject did not solve the issue. I noticed that the RAM consumption start growing rapidly when more remote hosts became offline. Also CPU usage is higher than usual from that time.

Comment: Hmm... If that happens when remote computers are offline, it may be because you're running to many processes at once. Make sure you don't start querying the same remote computer repeatedly. (Make sure the timer that starts your monitoring thread is _not_ reentrant)